# How to create public google bucket with uniform_bucket_level_access enabled?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

I want to create publicly accessible Google Cloud Bucket with uniform_bucket_level_access enabled using terraform. All of the examples on provider's docs which are for public bucket does not contain this setting.

When I try to use:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_access_control" "public_rule" {
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.a_bucket.name
  role   = "READER"
  entity = "allUsers"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "a_bucket" {
  name          = <name>
  location      = <region>
  project       = var.project_id
  storage_class = "STANDARD"
  uniform_bucket_level_access = true
  versioning {
    enabled = false
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 Error: Error creating BucketAccessControl: googleapi: Error 400: Cannot use ACL API to update bucket policy when uniform bucket-level access is enabled. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access, invalid
```

If I remove the line for uniform access everything works as expected.
Do I have to use `google_storage_bucket_iam` resource for achieving this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `google_storage_bucket_iam`.  I like to use the member one so I don't accidentally clobber other IAM bindings, but you can use whatever your needs dictate.

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "member" {
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.a_bucket.name
  role   = "roles/storage.objectViewer"
  member = "allUsers"
}
```

EDIT: Use this instead of the `google_storage_bucket_access_controls` resource that you have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I manually add principle "allUsers" with permission objectViewer, in the permission tab of the bucket in "view by principle" mode I have "allUsers" which is of type group. But when I use your suggested code it is not present there.
Any idea why is that ?
I actually want to reproduce this: create bucket > add principal "allUsers" with "roles/storage.objectViewer".

Comment: I just created a bucket with your suggested solution and even though the principal "allUsers" is not shown in the UI , what I did as a "test" is try to add it manually and it said principal already exists.

Comment: If you click the hamburger (skewer?) menu on the far right of your bucket and go to "Edit access", that's where the "Storage Object Viewer" role would be added.

Comment: There seems to be a delay between the creation of the resource and when the row in question is rendered in the Google Cloud interface. Today it is shown in the UI.
Actually this is the reason for my question. At first I tried with the same code that you suggested but I did not saw it there so I thought I did something wrong.